# Change timezone for IBM Bluemix/Cloud Cloud foundry app

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a Python application running as a Cloud Foundry app.
The timezone for the entire container/vm for my application is UTC, even though it is deployed in the US south region.
It's not just that messages in the log files are from the future, but some parts of the application rely on the current time. I tried to change the time zone via SSH from the application's management page but of course I do not have permissions.
I notice something similar on DSX.
Questions:

How do I change the time zone for the application and the container/vm it is running in?

Shouldn't the timezone be set to whatever region it is deployed in?

Comment: Do you always know which exact timezone the data center (and its backups) are in? Many enterprise services/apps are hosted across continents for high availability and load balancing.

Comment: It’s considered a best practice for log files to be written in utc.  Can you share more information on the application code that needs the local time?

Comment: Sounds like your app isn't handling times correctly.  Handle everything in UTC internally and where you display times to users do so in their local time.

Comment: The application is a fileserver. So the problem is that the files on the local filesystem where the application is running have modificiation timestamps in UTC.
 So downloading a file with a timestamp 4 hours in the future is problematic for certain scenarios, like using them with Makefiles.
I know it is possible to modify my application to set the timestamp but now that forces the application to pick a timezone, since the application and container are all on UTC.